# Continuously updating label color

Tags: c#, colors, label

I am showcasing whether someone's connected via Always-On VPN - green = connected, red = disconnected.
However, this only works when the application has started and I would like for it to continuously update the color of the label, if it suddenly disconnects and when you connect it again

Here's the code:

```
public bool CheckForVPNInterface()
        {
            if (NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
            {
                NetworkInterface[] interfaces = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();

                foreach (NetworkInterface networkInterfaces in interfaces)
                {
                    if (networkInterfaces.Description.Contains("Always-On VPN") && networkInterfaces.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
                    {
                        Label_Connection.BackColor = Color.Green;
                        Button_ConnectVPN.Text = "Disconnect";
                        return true;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Label_Connection.BackColor = Color.Red;
                        Button_ConnectVPN.Text = "Connect";
                    }
                }
                
            }
            return false;    
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this function is only called once when the application starts. It may be necessary to try this process within a certain time using the timer.

```
aTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();
aTimer.Interval = 500; //doing a check every half second
aTimer.Elapsed += CheckForVPNInterface;
```

`aTimer.Elapsed += CheckForVPNInterface;`  this code will run automatically every half second.

But I would not recommend calling this operation async. There will be error. This will require changes in certain places in the code. For this you will need to Invoke where it should work in the UI widget.

Comment: Thanks for your comment!
I am not too sure on how to implement this - could you try and be a bit more elaborate?

Comment: @MadsBrockmannJuhl What exactly is your project? İ need full answer for help in detail